# How get reference to collection in WCF C#?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two WCF servies in one solution:

- Wcf.BLL
- Wcf.model

I have an additional class `RegistrationList` in service `Wcf.model` with the following code:

```
 namespace Wcf.model
    {
        class RegistrationList
        {

            [Required]

            public string Login { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string Password { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

How I can get access to `RegistrationList` from my `ServiceContract` of first service `Wcf.BLL`, that to set parameter with type `RegistrationList`?

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IWcf.BLL
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string Register(RegistrationList Login); // Here I can set type as `RegistrationList`

    }
```

Comment: Can you please try to improve the quality of your question? It's not very clear what you want to do nor what's not working

Comment: Did some changes in question, hope It is more clear

Comment: Have you already added the project reference to Wcf.Model in Wcf.BLL?

Comment: Yes, but inside `Wcf.Model` I have separeted class (file) `RegistrationList`

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify any access modifier for the `RegistrationList` class. The default is `internal`, so it's only available in `Wcf.model` assembly.

If you want to use `RegistrationList` in another assembly, make it `public`

```
public class RegistrationList
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: You could also add InternalsVisibleTo if you want to keep it internal.

Comment: It does not help me. I dont see class `RegistrationList` method in `Wcf.model` when do: `Wcf.model.RegistrationList`

Comment: I do request to separated class in WCF service, may be is it reason?

Comment: @Ahmed Make sure you added a reference to `Wcf.Model` project in `Wcf.BLL`